# TargetInvocationException on manuel execution, debugger runs fine

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, targetinvocationexception

My application works just fine running in the VS 2013 debugger. When starting the app manually (debug.exe) I get the following exception:

```
06.11.2015 13:31:08 WiiLogger\: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Property accessor 'MainViewModel' on object 'MyTool.ViewModels.ViewModelLocator' threw the following exception:'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'
```

Here is the MVVM Light Locator code:
ctor:

```
public ViewModelLocator()
{
    ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MyRepository>();
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<TrayContextMenuViewModel>();
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<EmployeeListViewModel>();
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<SettingsViewModel>();
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
}
```

Property

```
public MainViewModel MainViewModel
{
    get
    {
        return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
    }
}
```

I create the instance like this in MainWindow.xaml:

```
<DockPanel x:Name="MainPanel"  DataContext="{Binding MainViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
```

And here is my CTOR for my MainViewModel:

```
public MainViewModel(EmployeeListViewModel emplyeeVM, TrayContextMenuViewModel trayVM, SettingsViewModel settingsVM, WiiRepository repository)
```

I really don't understand why the application works when starting via Visual Studio 2013, but it crashes when I start it manually :/

Comment: Have you tried running it in **release** mode using Visual Studio?

Comment: I figured I can run the application with administrator rights. In one of my ViewModels I use a RegistryHelper to set some stuff ... it's in the 3rd level of InnerExceptions ... that's the problem I guess :/